# How to replace class of the elements having a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Current code is `<i class="arrow-right"></i>`

I want to replace class in all `<i>` elements having "arrow-right" with "new-arrows"

I tried it using JS.

```
function changeclass(newclass, elm) {
    elm.attr('class', function (i, oldClasses) {
        return newclass: oldClasses.replace(/\b(bg-[a-z]+)\b/i, return newclass;
    });
}

$('i').each(function () {
    changeclass('new-arrows', $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggleClass()` for this:

```
$('i.arrow-right').toggleClass('arrow-right new-arrows');
```